# htaccess query_string redirect only when string equals a specific value

Tags: .htaccess

I've been searching for hours on how to do this and feel as if I'm close.

I am trying to redirect specific visitors to a different page on my site based on the string parameters passed in the URL.

For exmaple, I want the URL mysite.com/index.php?src=msn&test=1 to be redirected to mysite.com/msn/index.php?src=msn&test=1

I am planning on my normal site visitors to access the index.php page without being re-directed, so it should only redirect when the query string matches the value I set.

Here is my code:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^src=msn(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/msn/ [L]
```

The above code works when I go to the URL mysite.com/?src=msn&test=1 but it does not work for mysite.com/index.php?src=msn&test=1.  Any idea how I can get it to work when I enter index.php?

Thanks.

EDIT:::

I also have the following rules in my .htaccess file:

```
 ErrorDocument 404 /error404.php

 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /blog/
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
 </IfModule>

 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite\.com$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The first is a 404 redirect, second is a wordpress file change, and the last forces all pages to be http://www.

Comment: Do you have any other rules in your htaccess?

Comment: Ulrich, I've updated the original post to show the other rules in .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

> RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]

prevents index.php from further processing.

The easiest solution is to move your new rules to the top as below ( I assume they are all in the same .htaccess file)

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error404.php

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /blog/

#rule to add www to domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#new rule to redirect based on query string param
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^src=msn(.*)$
#unless it is already msn
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/msn/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/msn/ [L,R]

#rules for blogs
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense now.  I apologize for my basic understanding of .htaccess, but the problem I have now is I cannot prevent the rule from applying to the page I'm re-directing to and thus I'm entering into an infinite loop.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @user1167727 Added an extra condition to prevent this above